# IIS6 - Switching from .Net 2 to .Net 4 produces error “Declined to show web page”

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, mvc, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple website (http://localhost:8889) on Windows Server 2003 and IIS6. There is nothing in this website except a page called default.htm containing a simple text string. The page is served up properly if I specify .Net 2.0 on the ASP.Net page. If I specify .Net 4.0, the browser displays a page saying the server declined to serve the page.

The same configuration was tried on a WS2003 system running in a Microsoft Virtual PC and it worked fine.

(I'm trying to deploy an MVC site that requires .Net 4.0, the question is distilled down to what I believe is the fundemantal problem.)

Can anyone help?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that .Net 4 and .Net 2 sites can't use the same user process.  (I found an error in the Applicatin event log.)  All I had to do to fix the problem was create and use a new app pool for the new site.